# Is it necessary to stop iptables when you behind router to access your httpd (centos on wmware)?

Tags: virtualization, iptables, centos5

I have a strange behavior when I try to access my web server that is listening on port 8011
I did configure iptables to enable this port and its looks like this:

```
> :INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] :FORWARD ACCEPT
> [0:0] :OUTPUT ACCEPT [844:101801]
> :RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
> -A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
> -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8011 -j ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 81 -j ACCEPT
> -A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -d 224.0.0.251 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
> -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Im running the server Centos 5.5 on wmware and im trying to access the web server from the same local pc 
When I try to access to the web server from witin the Centos with lynx 10.0.0.3:8011
I can access fine to the server .
So does closing the iptable is the only solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it right. the problem is your packet is never making it back to the INPUT chain because there is a default reject that matches everything that doesn't have an allow at the end of RH-Firewall-1-INPUT.

To break down what is happening in your chain:

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] :FORWARD ACCEPT
[0:0] :OUTPUT ACCEPT [844:101801]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
```

Everything in the input interface is going to be processed by RH-Firewall-1-INPUT, we will return here if the packet doesn't get matched by the chain.

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8011 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 81 -j ACCEPT
```

These will be processed AFTER RH-Firewall-1-INPUT if and only if there is no match.

```
-A FORWARD -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
```

You're forward chain also has the RH-Firewall-1-INPUT rules applied

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -d 224.0.0.251 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

This is some default RH stuff
    -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
This rule matches *ALL* packets. and rejects them, since we are matching all packets we never return to the INPUT chain.

You can do a couple of things to fix this. My first suggestion is the one I reccomend to keep things uniform. You would modify the RH-Firewall-1-INPUT chain like so:

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 8011 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m state --state NEW--dport 81 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -d 224.0.0.251 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

You're second option would be to jump after you're input rules. I really don't suggest it since it can lead to some ugly rules, but is a valid solution so i'll put it here:

```
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] :FORWARD ACCEPT
[0:0] :OUTPUT ACCEPT [844:101801]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8011 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 81 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
```

Answer (score 0):

As your using VMWare the chances are the virtual machines network is different to yours for instance your netmask could be different etc, if you do a ipconfig on the Windows machine and a ifconfig on the centos box and post the results you may get a better answer.